# adding each element of NSMutableIndexSet by 1

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I have a NSMutableIndexSet and I want to be able to add and store the index set by 1, planning to use a block to do it, here's what I have so far:

```
[indexes enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            //add and store back the set here
            idx++;
}];
```

is there a way to iterate and modify at the same time? if yes how? the code above doesn't seem to work

Comment: Try to explain a more about what your starting point is and what you are trying to accomplish. But basically, no you can not enumerate and modify the `NSMutableIndexSet` you are enumerating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not enumerate and modify the NSMutableIndexSet you are enumerating. Just create a new NSMutableIndexSet and add the entries to it. It is doubtful that there is a performance hit.

Example (with ARC):

```
NSMutableIndexSet *originalIndexSet = [NSMutableIndexSet new];
[originalIndexSet addIndex:1];
[originalIndexSet addIndex:5];

NSMutableIndexSet *newIndexSet = [NSMutableIndexSet new];
[originalIndexSet enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [newIndexSet addIndex:idx+1];
}];

NSLog(@"originalIndexSet: %@", originalIndexSet);
NSLog(@"newIndexSet:      %@", newIndexSet);
```

Then

```
originalIndexSet = newIndexSet;
```

NSLog output:

> originalIndexSet: [number of indexes: 2 (in 2 ranges), indexes: (1 5)]
>   newIndexSet:   [number of indexes: 2 (in 2 ranges), indexes: (2 6)]